# Trying to replicate a '=countifs' function from excel to SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have an excel file with a table that looks like this:

```
     A                          B                             C
Registry ID             Parent Reg ID                   Focus Account (Y/N)
100000033               100000036778                          Y
100000343               1000                                  Y
1000343223              100000036778                          N
```

And the formula is on the column D (Focus Parent): `=IF(COUNTIFS(C:C,"Y",B:B,B)>=1,"Y","N")`

So on the column D the formula returns 'Y' for each row.

I've tried to replicate this in SQL with the following code:

```
SELECT 
    REGISTRY_ID,
    PARENT_REG_ID,
    FOCUS_ACCOUNT,
    SCORE_DETAILS,
    (CASE
     WHEN FOCUS_ACCOUNT = 'Y' THEN 
                            (CASE
                                    WHEN COUNT(PARENT_REG_ID) >= 1 THEN 'Y'
                                        ELSE 'N'
                            END)
     ELSE 'N'
    END) AS Focus_Parent
FROM MA_ACCOUNTS
```

But this query returns this error:

> ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Can you please advise?

**Later edit:**

Let me clarify this: I have a list with unique Registry_IDs that contain a Parent_Registry_ID. A Parent_Registry_ID can have multiple Registry_ID but if a Registry_ID is marked as ‘Y’ in the Column Focus_Account then that Parent_Registry_ID should have ‘Y’ in the column Focus_Parent.

```
 Registry ID    Parent Reg ID   Focus Account (Y/N)
1                     A                 N
2                     B                 N
3                     A                 Y
4                     C                 Y
5                     A                 N
6                     B                 Y
7                     A                 N
8                     D                 Y
9                     E                 N
10                    E                 N
```

Expected outcome:

```
   Registry ID      Parent Reg ID   Focus Account (Y/N)     Focus Parent (Y/N)
        1                 A                N                      Y
        2                 B                N                      Y
        3                 A                Y                      Y
        4                 C                Y                      Y
        5                 A                N                      Y
        6                 B                Y                      Y
        7                 A                N                      Y
        8                 D                Y                      Y
        9                 E                N                      N
       10                 E                N                      N
```

Comment: share your expected output

Comment: You are using `COUNT(PARENT_REG_ID)` in the `SELECT`, so expecting the `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an aggregated `count()` so Oracle is expecting a GROUP BY clause. However, that would not fit the shape of your result set. Seems like an analytic function would be better?

You have posted a clarification which I think defines this rule:

> if any `registry_id` has `focus_account='Y'` then set `focus_parent = 'Y'` for all instances of its `parent_reg_id`.

If my interpretation is correct you can implement it quite simply with an analytic `max()`:

```
select 
    registry_id,
    parent_reg_id,
    focus_account,
    max( focus_account ) over (partition by parent_reg_id) as focus_parent
from ma_accounts
```

This works because `focus_account` is a Y/N flag. Certainly the above query produces your revised result set from the posted input data.

Comment: It works! I also found that this code is working as well: `SELECT M.*,NVL(x.FOCUS_ACCOUNT,'N') FROM MA_ACCOUNTS M
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT PARENT_REG_ID, FOCUS_ACCOUNT FROM MA_ACCOUNTS WHERE FOCUS_ACCOUNT = 'Y') X ON X.PARENT_REG_ID = M.PARENT_REG_ID` Thank you for your answer!

Comment: You're welcome. Often we find that specifying a clear requirement is the key to getting a timely and helpful solution :D

Answer (score 0):

Your using an aggregate method in the select section, but your not grouping at the end for the other selected variables.

Try:

```
SELECT 
    REGISTRY_ID,
    PARENT_REG_ID,
    FOCUS_ACCOUNT,
    SCORE_DETAILS,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(PARENT_REG_ID) >= 1 AND FOCUS_ACCOUNT = 'Y' THEN 'Y'
         ELSE 'N' END AS Focus_Parent
FROM MA_ACCOUNTS
GROUP BY REGISTRY_ID,
    PARENT_REG_ID,
    FOCUS_ACCOUNT,
    SCORE_DETAILS
```

Comment: Grouping by all the columns in the projection will change the calculation of `focus_parent`. The Excel version counts the occurrences of  just `PARENT_REG_ID`.